# Boost priority_queue iterators

Tags: c++, boost

I am taking a crack at learning Boost. I wanted to take a look at heap::priority_queue.

I am trying to iterate over the priority queue, however I am having difficulties with user defined types.
I have noticed that

```
    boost::heap::priority_queue<int>::iterator it1; //works fine
    boost::heap::priority_queue<myClass*>::iterator it2; //compiler error
```

The second declaration is causing a compiler error

```
    error: no matching function call for call to boost::iterator_adapter...
```

What would be the reasoning behind this?

Edit 1: Sorry, I meant to put down myClass* instead of the other way around, this has been fixed. Slip on my part. The full error message is:

```
/usr/include/boost/heap/detail/stable_heap.hpp|534|error:
  no matching function for call to
   ‘boost::iterator_adaptor<boost::heap::detail::stable_heap_iterator<
        myClass*, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<myClass* const*, 
          std::vector<myClass*, std::allocator<myClass*> > >, 
      boost::heap::detail::heap_base<myClass*, std::less<myClass*>, false, long unsigned int, false> >,
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<myClass* const*, std::vector<myClass*, std::allocator<myClass*> > >,
    myClass* const,
    boost::random_access_traversal_tag, 
    boost::use_default,
    boost::use_default>
      ::iterator_adaptor(int)’
```

Edit 2: Imagine myClass is defined like this:

```
    class myClass
    {
         private:
              int value;
         public:
              inline int getValue() { return this->value; }
              inline void setValue(int v) { this->value = v; }
    }
```

Very simple.

Comment: `*myClass` is nonsense.  Can you clarify?  And post the full complete error message.

Comment: Do you get the error just from creating `it2` or from using it?  Can you show a complete, minimal example that produces the error?

Comment: The error message occurs when it is declared, as shown above.

Comment: New edit, shows the simplest example of myClass.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `iterator` type in `boost::heap::priority_queue` is not default constructible.  You can, however, do this:

```
typedef boost::heap::priority_queue<myClass*> queue_t;
queue_t queue;
queue_t::iterator it2 = queue.begin();
```

Comment: This produces the same error.  Isn't this essentially just a more verbose way of doing the same thing above? What do you mean when you say "not default constructible"?

Comment: I mean (at least on my system!) that you cannot create an iterator without initializing it.  What Boost version, OS, and compiler are you using?